# Value tracking in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, resharper, static-analysis

Do Eclipse's Java tools have any equivalent (built-in or plugin) to the [Value Tracking](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2010/03/resharper-50-preview-value-tracking/) inspection in ReSharper? This would be similar to a Call Hierarchy, but tracks all previous value assignments and argument passes for a particular variable.

To clarify, I'm looking for a tool that uses static analysis to trace the origin of a value, within the IDE; this is not debugging at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Use the debugger mode in eclipse is very powerful. (Add watches!)

Comment: I'm actually looking for a static analysis solution, not something that can be done in a debugger.

Answer (score 1):

Highlight the variable and then press Control+Shift+G or Right Click->References->Workspace will get you all of the references of a particular variable, and you can see where it was assigned or passed as an argument that way. It will show up in a window on the bottom, and a double click will take you directly to the reference.

Comment: This is useful, but equivalent to the "Find Usages" command in Jetbrains products.